# Existence of a metric on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}^d\backslash\{0\}$ such that

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I found the following proposition and I'm looking for a proof, a book where I can find the proof (that I can quote) or the metric itself. The proposition goes:

> There exists a metric $\rho$ such that $(\overline{\mathbb{R}}^d\backslash\{\mathbf{0}\},\rho)$ is a locally compact, complete and separable metric space.

Notation: $\overline{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R}\cup \{-\infty,\infty\}$, $d\in\mathbb{N}$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does the 'd' stand for? and what is the topology that the metric is supposed to induce?

Comment: Are there other conditions? There exists a bijection between your set and the set $\mathbb R$. The usual metric on $\mathbb R$ makes it into a locally compact, complete, separable space. Simply transport the metric through the bijection.

Comment: sorry, it's dimension, so $d\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: No there aren't. All I need is to specify a topology on this space. Do you mind telling me the bijection?
In fact, the existence is sufficient.

Comment: The bijection comes from basic set theory, an infinite set $X$ is in bijection with $X^2$ (and by induction, $X^d$ for every $d$).

Comment: @DimaMcGreen without further requirements of the metric (such as a particular topology for it to induce) the question has little content. The reason is that you are just looking for a metric on a particular *set*, not a space. That set has cardinality $c$, and thus is in bijection with, e.g., $[0,1]$. Transport the metric from $[0,1]$ along this bijection and you are done. Presumably, there is some underlying topology that is to be taken into consideration here in order to make the question more interesting.

Comment: The proposition isn't making any requirements and is as I found it. I was just looking for a proof.

My situation is the following: I need a topology on this space, such that sets that are bounded away from $0$ are compact, e.g. $[\mathbf{a},\mathbf{\infty}]$ is compact, where $\mathbf{a}\in\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: oh, obviously it has to be $\mathbf{a}\in(0,\infty]^d$, sorry...

Comment: @DimaMcGreen: That requirement that $[a,\infty]$ be compact changes everything, just so you know...

Answer (score 2):

Consider the set $M = [-1,\,1]^d \setminus \{0\}$. Let $F = \{ (x,t) \in M\times\mathbb{R} : t\cdot\lvert x\rvert = 1\}$.

$F$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$, hence complete in the induced (euclidean, sum of absolute values, maximum of absolute values, ...) metric. The projection $\pi \colon (x,t) \mapsto x$ is a homeomorphism between $M$ and $F$. ($F$ is the graph of the continuous function $x \mapsto \frac{1}{\lvert x\rvert}$.)

Let $\varphi \colon \overline{R} \to [-1,\,1]; \; \varphi(y) = \frac{y}{1+\lvert y\rvert}$. $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism. Applying it componentwise gives a homeomorphism $\overline{\mathbb{R}}^d \to [-1,\,1]^d$ that induces a homeomorphism $\overline{\mathbb{R}}^d\setminus\{0\} \to [-1,\,1]^d\setminus\{0\} = M$.

Transporting the metric from $F$ to $\overline{\mathbb{R}}^d\setminus\{0\}$ via the projection and $\varphi^d$ gives a metric that has the required properties.

Comment: Does it make things simpler if take $d=1$ and then use the product metric?

Comment: Doesn't work, unfortunately, because $\overline{\mathbb{R}}^d\setminus\{0\}$ is not a product. Do you really need the metric? Normally, knowing its existence is enough.

Comment: Oh sure, you're right. I mixed up a bit, since I will need the product space $([-\infty,\infty]\backslash\{0\})^d$ as well. :)

The existence is enough. So if I prove your statements, I'm good to go right?

Comment: On that product space, the product metric would work fine (on $[-\infty,\,0) \cup (0,\,+\infty]$, you can make it easier by identifying that with $(-\infty,\,-1] \cup [1,\, +\infty)$ per $1/x\pm 1$). There's not much to prove (except I made a typo, going to fix).

Comment: $x \mapsto (x,\, 1/\lvert x\rvert)$ is a continuous bijection $M \to F$ with continuous inverse $(x,\,t) \mapsto x$. $F$ is closed as the intersection of the closed sets $\{(x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R} : t\cdot \lvert x\rvert = 1\}$ and $\{(x,t) : \lvert x_i\rvert \leqslant 1,\, 1\leqslant i \leqslant d\}$. $\varphi$'s inverse is $z \mapsto \frac{z}{1-\lvert z\rvert}$.

Comment: :) I will need to work through your manual, since it's pretty new to me.
As for $[-\infty,\infty]\backslash\{0\}$, I could just stick to the relative topology (you helped me with the metric on $[-\infty,\infty]$), right? (Sorry for this mundane question)

Comment: Everything here uses the relative topology with respect to the standard topology on the containing space, but to get completeness when a point is removed, the metric must be changed in a way that the removed point would no longer be reachable (you must make all sequences originally converging to that point into non-Cauchy sequences). The existence of such metrics is standard, ways to construct them are too, but usually, the constructed metric isn't too nice.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9944/discussion-between-dima-mcgreen-and-daniel-fischer)